# How does the Spring BOM approach to releases and dependencies work?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am relatively new to Maven and the JVM and am curious how Spring's approach to releases actually works? What is a BOM?

For example, the Spring Cloud page says `Use your dependency management tools to control the version. If you are using Maven remember that the first version declared wins, so declare the BOMs in order, with the first one usually being the most recent (e.g. if you want to use Spring Boot 1.3.6 with Brixton.RELEASE, put the Boot BOM first).`

Can someone give an example of what this means in practice?

Answer (score 0):

You detected the Maven concept of [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management). The Maven documentation illustrates that concept quite well. You will also find information anbout the ***B**ill **O**f **M**aterials* (BOM) in the Maven documentation.

In short a BOM defines dependencies (with versions) and projects that import this BOM will get the version information for the atrifacts they depend on from the BOM. Thus a BOM can ensure that a set of dependencies is used with versions that are "compatible" with each other.